# how to download pdf from Amazon usning amazon S3 framework

Tags: objective-c

i tried searching but can't find better, i also tried above code but it beyond of my understanding and give me many errors please help me out....

```
S3GetPreSignedURLRequest * request = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
request.bucket = @"bucket";
request.key = @"key";
request.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
request.httpVerb = @"GET";

AmazonCredentials *credentials = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
request.credentials = credentials;

NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setHour:1];
NSDate * oneHourFromNow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

request.expires = oneHourFromNow;

//get the presigned URL
//NSURL * url = [[Constants s3] getPreSignedURL: request];
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the secret in an application and creating a presigned URL on the spot doesn't make sense. iOS applications **should not** include S3 secrets, as those can be used to do things that you will almost assuredly not want your users to do (e.g, uploading and deleting files, creating and deleting buckets, etc).

If you want the PDF to be publicly accessible, set it as public when you upload it, and it will be available at its URL using any HTTP library (e.g, http://s3.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/yourfile.pdf). You do not need the S3 framework to do this - `NSURLConnection`, or even just a web view, will work just fine.

Comment: If you're including code to access the PDF in your application, it must be publicly accessible. The only question is really just how you go about making it public, and what other risks you want to expose yourself to in the process.

Comment: i am just freaking out i tried from 2 days but can't find any thing usefull please can you send me a complete and simple tutorial or example :(